# Phonon::Path and Phonon::Effect continue to work even if they are destroyed

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

Consider the following code.

```
class MainWindow
{
    // ...
    Phonon::MediaObject media;
    Phonon::AudioOutput audio_output;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow() : audio_output(MusicCategory)
{
    //...

    QList<EffectDescription> effects =
                          BackendCapabilities::availableAudioEffects();

    media.setCurrentSource(MediaSource("../test.wma"));
    Path path = createPath(&media, &audio_output);
    Q_ASSERT(path.isValid());

    if (!effects.isEmpty())
    {
        path.insertEffect(effects[2]);
    }

    media.play();

    qDebug() << "Playing...";
}
```

After the constructor returns, `path` and `effects` will be destroyed. I've noticed that the `media` continues to play even with the effect applied (`effects[2]`).

I think I missed something. Even if `path` and `effects` are destroyed, how does `media` continue to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As The [Path::~Path documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-path.html#dtor.Path) says:

> Destroys this reference to the Path. If the path was valid the connection is not broken as both the source and the sink MediaNodes still keep a reference to the Path.

That means that paths are more like handles than following RAII principles.
You have to explicitely call disconnect() to destroy the connection.